# Why router in Express/node.js return 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, http-status-code-404

I just generated Express app and added custom route (/configuration). But if I try to open http://localhost:3000/configuration, server returns 404 Not Found error. I checked the code and don't understand where is error.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var config_page = require('./routes/configuration');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/configuration', config_page);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**routes/configuration.js** (routes/index.js is similar)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET configuration page. */
router.get('/configuration', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('configuration', { title: 'My App | Configuration' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is the problem

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

Also the current Url which is generated by your application is **http://localhost:3000/configuration/configuration**. If you make a query on this then it will work. Now if you wan to use it with  **http://localhost:3000/configuration**. then you need to remove on path from anywhere. May be you can change in main file like this

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/',config_page); //-----------> this is the line you need to change
```

How can it be used for error handling. Remove it and add this code to catch any error in application.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  // This should not happen
  logger.error("Pheew ....! Something unexpected happened. This should be handled more gracefully. I am sorry. The culprit is: ", err);
});
```

Comment: Now it returns 'Cannot GET /configuration'

Comment: I believe the "Cannot GET /xyz" message is the default 404 message. Also not sure how this answer would change anything either, as long as the error handling is at the end it shouldn't interfere. I'm pretty sure 404 errors don't count as uncaught exceptions anyway

Comment: I just noticed that if you store all routing in one file (for example, index.js), then everything works fine. But if for each page you create a separate **.js** in **routes**, then the server starts to return a 404 error for all pages except the main page. I can not understand the logic of the router in Express...

Comment: @mxsin, I updated mu answer. It should work for you.